# JQuery Navigation Menu Issue with SubMenu

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having a problem determining why there are lines at the top of the sub-menu for a JQuery menu that I'm trying to implement.  This problem does not exist when I run the demo and I'm using the same browser.  I downloaded the demo from here:  http://apycom.com/menus/11-black.html

[image]

Here is the link for the development site: http:www.websitedevelopers.com

Thank you in advance for your insight into this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those lines were border-top and border-bottom set for li tag as below,

```
#menu ul.menu li div ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #70757B;
    border-top: 1px solid #31363B;
}
```

And the `float:left` defined for the menu seems to mess up the li items,

menu.css -> line 24

```
#menu * {
    float: left;  <--- Remove this
    ...
    ...
```

Please remove the `float:left` from above and try.

Comment: That did the trick, I had added that float because of an earlier problem I had with the content div below it